# FireFox -setDefaultBrowser does not work in XP?

Tags: firefox

Im trying to run a script that will set firefox as the default browser (in windows xp).

According to [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Setting_Your_Default_Browser) site, I can run `firefox.exe -silent -setDefaultBrowser` and it should set firefox as the default browser. I have tried this, but cannot seem to get it to work. I also tried without the -silent. It just launched and mocked me by asking if I wanted to set firefox as the default browser.

Any ideas how I can set firefox as the default browser in Windows XP via command line if this will not work?

Note: My Firefox version is 15.0.1

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have. It is always a good idea to state what version of something you have. Thanks.